# How to save the result of a SQL query as an integer in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a basic SQL query, which will always return a single number. I'd like to save this number as a python variable in integer format, so I can do some basic maths with it. Does anyone know how to do this please?

This is my first attempt, using pandas:

```
my_variable = pd.read_sql_query(
sql = 
f'''
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT ACCOUNT_NUMBER) AS ACCOUNTS 
FROM    MY_TABLE
;
''',
con = my_connection)

my_variable = my_variable["accounts"].astype(int)

if my_variable > 10000:
    print("success")
else:
    print("failure")
```

However, it results in the following error, presumably because while astype is converting the column to integer format, my_variable itself is still a dataframe.

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I also tried it using the execute statement in sqlalchemy so that the result would not be a dataframe:

```
my_variable = my_connection.execute(
f'''
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT ACCOUNT_NUMBER) AS ACCOUNTS 
FROM    MY_TABLE
;
''')

if my_variable > 10000:
    print("success")
else:
    print("failure")
```

However, this gave me the following error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'LegacyCursorResult' and 'float'
```

Does anyone know how to save my SQL result as an integer please?

Comment: `my_variable.scalar_one()` in SQLAlchemy should give you a single int: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.scalar_one

Comment: @slothrop thanks! This works, but oddly enough I can only seem to use scalar_one once. For example, if I add print(my_variable.scalar_one()) before the if statement as a test, the print statement works but the if statement returns "sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object is closed." If I remove the print statement the if statement works fine. Do you know why this is please?

Comment: the object called `my_variable` represents a stateful cursor over the database query. It helps to think of it as a "result provider" rather than a "result" per se. So once you've already extracted a result from it with `scalar_one`, it's been exhausted and won't return a result again. You can of course do something like `res = my_variable.scalar_one()` and use that `res` subsequently as many times as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Use the SQLAlchemy `scalar` method, which will return the result or `None`.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

engine = create_engine("<YOUR DATABASE URI>")

with engine.connect() as my_connection:
    my_variable = my_connection.execute(text(
"""
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT ACCOUNT_NUMBER) AS ACCOUNTS 
FROM    MY_TABLE;
""")).scalar()

print(type(my_variable)) # int
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer has been provided in the comments by slothrop:

> res = my_variable.scalar_one()